# Java, Insert a {} pair to make the code segment work as it should

Tags: java, boolean, semantics

The following code fragment is supposed to print "Type AB" when `boolean` variables `typeA` and `typeB` are both true, and print "Type O" when both variables are false. Instead, it prints "Type O" whenever just one of the variables is false.

I don't see the error in the code, what's wrong with it? I think it's useless as it doesn't print out whether one is Type A or Type B. Why not insert System.out.print("Type A") or System.out.print("Type B") after the first line?

```
if (typeA || type B)
    if (typeA && typeB)
        System.out.print("Type AB");
    else 
        System.out.print("Type O");
```

Comment: "code snippets" are for HTML/CSS/JS. Java code should be wrappedn in "code sample" since you can't run it in browser.

Comment: You have run across the [*dangling else*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) issue.  Probably, this was an educational example to make you aware of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would fix the conditions :

```
if (typeA || type B) {
  if (typeA && typeB)
    System.out.print("Type AB");
} else {
    System.out.print("Type O");
}
```

Without the curly braces, the else would be matched to the inner if, but you want to match it to the outer if.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code gets compile like this:

```
if (typeA || type B)
  if (typeA && typeB)
    System.out.print("Type AB");
  else 
    System.out.print("Type O");
```

So, the IDE you use thinks that you might have meant to do it differently (because of your intendation that does not fit the way is is going to be compiled) and suggests you to add brackets to make it work like you want it (and the way that fits the indentation you used):

```
if (typeA || type B)
{
  if (typeA && typeB)
    System.out.print("Type AB");
}
else 
{
  System.out.print("Type O");
}
```